# How to patents a design Idea for a device

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent, design

Good day,
Please how do I get a patent for a design Idea that I have so that Someone doesnt not go behind to create the same device and I loose in all?

Thank you

Comment: Answering this would fill a book and then some. If you have a specific question about the process, feel free to come back here to ask, but asking simply "how to patent" is too broad for this site.

Comment: It might help if you could differentiate between whether you are seeking to protect he 'look' of something (a design patent) or a tangible mechanism/process (utility patent). Then, if you could give a few broad details it might help people at least point you in the right direction to get started.